# Convert Any to Map[String, String] in Play Framework

Tags: scala, templates, dictionary, playframework-2.0

I receive some data from database and then I need to print them. I use List of Map[String, Any] to pass data to my template. Actually, there is Map[String, String] inside that first Map. But I can't access it. It's not possible to use ajax or other client-side tools because there's too much data. Are there any ideas?
Here is a piece of code:

```
val result = dlgs().map( row =>
    Map(
       "id" -> row[Int]("id"),
       "dlg_type" -> row[String]("type"),
       "info" -> Json.parse(row[String]("info")).asOpt[Map[String, String]]
    )
).toList
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do, maybe you could describe the data you are trying to do, you have json in your database that you want to send to your client or you want to parse it and publish a subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using my own class instead of Map.